# ORA-01843: not a valid month error when using to_date function

Tags: sql, database, oracle, datetime, date-formatting

```
SELECT sysdate as today,
       to_date(CONCAT (to_char(sysdate,'MM-DD-YYYY'),
               to_char(sysdate,'hh24:mi:ss'))) as time
FROM DUAL
```

Every time I execute this query it gives me `ORA-01843: not a valid month`

Could someone please help me?

Comment: `to_date(CONCAT (to_char(sysdate,'MM-DD-YYYY'),
               to_char(sysdate,'hh24:mi:ss')))` will return exactly the same as sysdate. If you want to see time, you need `to_char(sysdate,'MM-DD-YYYY hh24:mi:ss')`

Comment: And `sysdate` is not "today", but "now". If you want to get rid of the time part use `trunc(sysdate)`. If you want to *display* the date part only, use to_char: e.g. `to_char(sysdate,'MM-DD-YYYY')`. If you select `sysdate` directly you get the full datetime and it's up to GUI settings how it gets displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you want to see time from sysdate, if so you need this select:

```
SELECT sysdate as today,
       to_char(sysdate,'MM-DD-YYYY hh24:mi:ss'))) as time
FROM DUAL
```

In your example wrong part is to_date, you should use mask for to_date:

```
to_date(CONCAT (to_char(sysdate,'MM-DD-YYYY'),
               to_char(sysdate,'hh24:mi:ss')),'MM-DD-YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
```

But this will return exactly the same as `sysdate` because both of this columns are date and the format of dates depends on variable NLS_DATE_FORMAT, check [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_nls_date_format_sysdate.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tatiana :)

Comment: @Tatiana Just a friendly suggestion, that site you pointed to doesn't have a good reputation in the Oracle community.

Answer (score 2):

> to_date(CONCAT (to_char(sysdate,'MM-DD-YYYY'),
>                  to_char(sysdate,'hh24:mi:ss'))) as time

It is simply useless what you are doing. You are extracting **date and time portions** separately and then converting it back to **DATE**. It is nothing but **SYSDATE** itself.

It would make sense if you are extracting and **displaying** the date and time elements. Or, you have date and time as **string literals** separately, and now you want to convert it into a **DATE**.

For example,

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT to_date(CONCAT ('01/11/2016', '14:45:20'), 'MM/DD/YYYYHH24:MI:SS') my_date
  2  FROM DUAL;

MY_DATE
-------------------
01/11/2016 14:45:20
```

> ORA-01843: not a valid month

**Reason**

This mostly happens due to **NLS dependency**. Since you are not using an explicit **format mask**, Oracle is trying to implicitly convert it based on your **locale-specific NLS settings**.

**Example**

Let's change the NLS format of the session:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='dd/mon/yyyyhh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.
```

Let's execute the same query:

```
SQL> SELECT to_date(CONCAT ('01/11/2016', '14:45:20')) my_date
  2  FROM DUAL;
SELECT to_date(CONCAT ('01/11/2016', '14:45:20')) my_date
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

As expected, it throws `ORA-01843: not a valid month`.